# MATLAB - Unsure of fullfile command syntax for path location

Tags: matlab, path, directory, data-storage

Here's a piece of code I'm working on, based on another example from a previous comment.

**In the first line, what do I make my path?**

Do I extend all the way back to `Macintosh HD/Users/..../Documents/MATLAB` (MATLAB folder in that path is where the `ascii` files I'm analyzing are stored) or do I start at another point?

**I'm just not sure what to replace the `path`, `to`, `folder`, with in the below example.**

I'm even more confused because the current `dir` shown in my MATLAB window is the correct one where the files I'm working with are stored.

In that case, what do I do with the `fullfile` line? I'm also trying to display the contents of the newly truncated files. How do I do that? Thanks!

```
folder = fullfile('path', 'to', 'folder');

  f = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.asc'));
  matrices = struct();
     for ii = 1 : numel(f)
         name = fullfile(folder, f(ii).name);
         O = dlmread(name);
         matrices.(f(ii).name) = O(1:80,:);
     end
```

Comment: If you have data in the MATLAB directory, you may be able to use `userpath`

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation says, [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) allows you to construct a filename from it's parts without having to worry whether to use / or \ as the file separators and without doing things the really messy way of old

```
filename = ['path' filesep 'to' filesep 'files'];
```

or even worse!

```
folder = '/path/to/file';
```

You'll run into all sorts of issues if you attempt to switch between operating systems.

In the example you have provided it could be

```
folder = fullfile('Users', 'Documents', 'MATLAB')
```

*Side Note: Please don't actually store your data in that folder*

You are correct that if the files you're trying to load are in your current directory, then you don't need the `folder` variable because if you just type `dlmread(filename)` it will work.

The issue though, is that is **requires** that the user be in a specific directory to run your code and it may not be clear to the user what folder that is. The code that you have provided is more robust because it doesn't depend on your current directory. In my mind it is best practice to never rely on the current directory. Nothing worse in my mind than seeing someone change directories within MATLAB just so they can access their data!

So keeping in mind what `fullfile` does, I'll annotate your code below

```
folder = fullfile('path', 'to', 'folder');
```

Stores the path to where your data lives. This can be either an absolute path (as you've stated in your question) `'/Users/blah/data'` or a path relative to the current directory `'data'` if your data lives in `fullfile(pwd, 'data')`. The former is my preferred method.

```
f = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.asc'));
```

This calls `dir` on looking for all files/folders with the `.asc` extension in that folder.

```
name = fullfile(folder, f(ii).name);
```

This line constructs the absolute path to the file of interest since `dir` only returns the filename, not the folder that it lives in (one of my biggest annoyances).

```
O = dlmread(name);
```

Then obviously this reads your actual file using the full path that is provided.

Again, the real benefit here is that you don't have to be in a specific directory to execute this code.

**So to answer you question directly**, now that you know about all of this. If your data lives in the current directory you *could* set `folder` to the current directory

```
folder = pwd;
```

Or if you want to be kind to others and your future self you can specify an absolute path (preferably passed as a function argument and not hard-coded)

```
function matrices = getfiles(folder)
    f = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.asc'));
    matrices = struct();
    for ii = 1 : numel(f)
        name = fullfile(folder, f(ii).name);
        O = dlmread(name);
        matrices.(f(ii).name) = O(1:80,:);
    end
end

matrices = getfiles(fullfile('user', 'defined', 'path', 'to', 'data'));
```

Comment: Ok, so if I do nothing more than replace folder = fullfile('path', 'to', 'folder'); with folder = pwd, that solves my directory confusion. But now how do I confirm (by displaying?) that this code actually only saved the first 80 rows as intended? Thanks!

Comment: @Svet I recommend reading the **whole** answer so you can understand why simply setting `folder = pwd` may be a bad idea.

Comment: @Svet as far as the first 80 rows, that's what this line does `matrices.(f(ii).name) = O(1:80,:);`. You can try it yourself to verify.

Comment: Ok, yeah, using folder = fullfile('Users',... 'MATLAB') is the best option here, assuming I won't move the data out of that folder for this specific routine.  Now why is it giving me an Invalid field name: 'filename.asc' error once I run this routine? If I remove that file, it goes to the next file in the folder and says the same thing, so it's not a one file error. Seems to be an error with all the ascii files that I'm trying to use in this routine!

Comment: @Svet yes this function does nothing to actually verify that these are valid files. It assumes that all .asc files are valid

Comment: To clarify, my previous question was not what that line does, but how to display those 80 rows. Also, I don't understand how MATLAB is storing each ascii files's first 80 rows.

Comment: @Svet I would ask those details in the thread where you got the code you posted here.

Comment: I'd say that the OP's use of `fullfile` in `dir(fullfile(folder, '*.asc'))` is kind of superfluous because its just concatenating an extension. It can be replaced with `dir([folder '*.asc'])`.

Comment: @horchler one of the primary benefits of fullfile is not worrying about whether your file path has a trailing slash or not.

Comment: @Suever: You're absolutely right, especially since the OP's first use of `fullfile` returns a path without a trailing separator.